# How to replace the preexisting images in the google doc on drive with new set of Images using python script?

Tags: google-docs-api

How to get image_id here? Please help!!!

```
 "replaceImage": {
    "imageObjectId": IMAGE_ID",
    "uri": REPLACED_IMAGE_URL,
    "imageReplaceMethod": IMAGE_REPLACE_METHOD,
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the image is on your drive you can either

- Go to the Drive UI, right-click on the image ->Share -> Get shareable link and retrieve the id as the part between `https://drive.google.com/file/d/` and  `/view?usp=sharing`:
  `https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/view?usp=sharing`
- Or use the method [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), narrowing the results by specifying the [q parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files), e.g.

  `mimeType = 'XXX' and name = 'XXX' and 'XXX' in parents`